# Prevent from editing record directly hitting url in cake php

Tags: php, cakephp

How to prevent user from hitting url directly in browser so that he can't edit record like this:

> `http://localhost/demo_cake/users/edit/7`

My edit code in controller is as given below, Please give any suggestions:

```
  public function edit() {

    $id = $this->request->params['pass'][0];

    $this->User->id = $id;

    if( $this->User->exists() ){

        if( $this->request->is( 'post' ) || $this->request->is( 'put' ) ){

            if( $this->User->save( $this->request->data ) ){

                $this->Session->setFlash('User was edited.');

                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

            }else{
                $this->Session->setFlash('Unable to edit user. Please, try again.');
            }

        }else{

            $this->request->data = $this->User->read();
        }

    }else{

        $this->Session->setFlash('The user you are trying to edit does not exist.');
        $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));

    }
  }
```

index.php

```
<h2>Users</h2>

<!-- link to add new users page -->
<div class='upper-right-opt'>
    <?php echo $this->Html->link( '+ New User', array( 'action' => 'add' ) ); ?>
</div>

<table style='padding:5px;'>
    <!-- table heading -->
    <tr style='background-color:#fff;'>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

<?php


    //loop to show all retrieved records
    foreach( $users as $user ){

        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>{$user['User']['id']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$user['User']['firstname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$user['User']['lastname']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$user['User']['username']}</td>";
            echo "<td>{$user['User']['email']}</td>";

            //here are the links to edit and delete actions
            echo "<td class='actions'>";
                echo $this->Html->link( 'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $user['User']['id']) );

                //in cakephp 2.0, we won't use get request for deleting records
                //we use post request (for security purposes)
                echo $this->Form->postLink( 'Delete', array(
                        'action' => 'delete', 
                        $user['User']['id']), array(
                            'confirm'=>'Are you sure you want to delete that user?' ) );
            echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>

</table>
```

Comment: if I were you I won't use link for editing/deleting data... use button instead.

Comment: BTW It's your localhost. :P

Comment: but i have to use link and i have updated my code to show how i'm using link.

Comment: You don't want sessions and you keep saying "_prevent user from editing record by entering url_" as if anyone here would know what exactly you mean. That certainly isn't the case, which is why you should add some more _technical_ details to your question, as to what exactly it is that you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Is it a question for hide URL ?

Comment: The short answer is "by implementing Authorization". How do you currently expect to differentiate between a user typing a url, and clicking a link to a url of the same format? If you only want users to be able to click on links - you'll need to (e.g.) implement some form of hash-based request authorization - similar to [nginx's secure link module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_secure_link_module.html).

Answer (score 3):

Normally you would check if the session's user id is the same user id of the record he is trying to change or if the session's user id has enough privileges to do so to other users.

Comment: No i Julio i don't have to use session here, i only want that to prevent user from editing records by entering url in browser something like this: http://localhost/demo_cake/Users/edit/7.

Comment: **First**... we cannot see anything in your `localhost/demo...`. It is only visible in your machine so... none of us has no idea of what you are trying to show us. **Second** - This IS sort of what you want. Even if you don't know that yet... there is no way to prevent one create a GET by trying to go to a valid URL or even do a valid POST by simulating a valid form. The only thing you can (must) do is validate everything that comes from the user.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
<button type="submit" name="cmd_edit" value="id_here">Edit</button>
```

Comment: This does not adress the stated problem.

Comment: @dbarthel you know what's bad about updating and deleting using url query string?... any user can mess with your data by putting any id on the url... best to put it on a button...

Comment: but i have to use link and i have updated my code to show how i'm using link.

Comment: the other answer should suffice.... check if that records belong to the $_SESSION user id..

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' You suggest "security by obscurity", which will never work. Most users won't be able to send a harmful request to the server, but its easy for a advanced user.

Comment: @dbarthel i don't want to use session or button but i only want to prevent user from editing record by entering url if he knows www.exampledomain.com/demo_cake/Users/edit/7.

Comment: @user3653474 unfortunately i dont know cakePHP, but it looks like you got a user-management in your php application. Now you need to check if the requesting user has sufficient rights do fulfill this operation. like in the other answer suggested

Answer (score 0):

You should use your own `isAuthorized(user=null){}` function and check if the user has the sufficient rights do fulfill this Operation. Have a look at [Authorization (who’s allowed to access what)](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authorization-who-s-allowed-to-access-what).